# i have wrote this line in gradle compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0' and still i am geeting error "cannot resolve symbol 'AuthUI'"

Tags: java, android

[image]

When I'm clicking on Install Repository and sync project link then nothing happens.

Comment: Install SDK & build tool version 26 and rebuild your project again it will work

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1' and  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this:

```
 maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

to project level build.gradle file look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

> The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven
>   repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the
>   SDK Manager, and that functionality will be removed soon.

More details [see here.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#download)

Edit: Also update your support library versions to `26.0.1` along with `compileSdkVersion to 26` and `buildToolsVersion to 26.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you put this line in your app level gradle file?
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: yes I have added this line

Comment: Add that previously mentioned line in project level gradle file and     
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' this one in app level gradle file    Try this once ...