# how can i add dependence when i got error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library, dependency-properties, firebaseui

I am trying to make an chat app with firebase and i need to add this two dependencies
`compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'`

my base compileSDKVersion is

```
ompileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

while i am trying to add two line of code dependencies segment i got this error

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.1.0
```

How can i make it right ? Thanks...

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422147/i-have-wrote-this-line-in-gradle-compile-com-firebaseuifirebase-ui-auth2-3-0/46422315#46422315

Comment: Thanks for helping it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

}
```

and in build.gradle(project )

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping its working now

Comment: @MertalpTaşdelen Using a old release (25.3.1) is **not the real solution**. You should use the latest versions and to do it you have to add the maven google repo.

Comment: then go for 26.0.0 it will also work for you.

Comment: mark answer correct for appreciation thanks.

Comment: you are right that we should use latest version but sometime latest versions have few problems 26.0.0 is stable and 25.3.1 and lower are but above 26.0.1 etc they are in beta version you can take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html